# Python - Сколько весит ссылка в list

Tags: python

`list` не хранит в себе непосредственно объекты, но хранит ссылки на них. Сколько весит такая ссылка?

Comment: В CPython список реализован как [массив указателей на PyObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c19c3a09618ac400538ee412f84be4c1196c7bab/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L8), так что, видимо, по 8 байт на ссылку (на 64-битных системах)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сама ссылка - 4 байта на 32 разряда, 8 байт на 64 разряда. @andreymal
прав:-)
Можно проверить самому (проверка ниже - на 64-разрядной системе):

```
    #56 байт выделено на пустой список, 64 - на одно число, 72 - на два
    import sys
    print(sys.getsizeof([]))                #56
    print(sys.getsizeof([12345678]))        #64 
    print(sys.getsizeof([12345678, 2.844])) #72
```